# Find common numbers in two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Given two sequences, is there a way to determine what numbers they 
will have in common, without the use of factoring?  For example,

Sequence 1: 22 (+21), 43 (+23), 66 (+25), 91
Sequence 2: 7 (+9), 16 (+11), 27, 40, 55, 72, 91

Each sequence has an initial number and an initial amount to add to get the next number.  Then the amount added increases by 2 in each step of the sequence. Finally, there is a final number in the sequence.

Is there a formula or algorithm to calculate either the common number/s or the position of the common number/s based on the two initial values and initial amounts to add?

Can this be done without having to use factoring as this won't work for large numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Modular arithmetic could help, as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505751/prove-no-two-numbers-besides-1-in-the-sequences-are-identical)

Answer (score 3):

First find a formula for the terms.

Let one of the series have first term $a$ and initial difference $d$. Then a formula for the $k$th term is $a+(k-1)d+(k-1)(k-2)$. [Ask if you aren't sure how to obtain this.]

Similarly, if the other series has first term $b$ and initial difference $e$, then a formula for the $l$th term is $b+(l-1)e+(l-1)(l-2)$.

The equation for two terms to be the same is therefore $$a+(k-1)d+(k-1)(k-2)=b+(l-1)e+(l-1)(l-2).$$

> Example: your series where $a=22,d=21,b=7,e=9$.

$$k^2+18k+3=l^2+6l$$
Complete the square on both sides.
$$(k+9)^2-78=(l+3)^2-9$$
Let $K=k+9,L=l+3.$
$$69=K^2-L^2=(K-L)(K+L)$$
Now consider the possible factors of $69$.

So $K-L=1,K+L=69$ or $K-L=3,K+L=23$.

The solutions are $K=35,L=34,k=26,l=31$ or the solution you found $K=13,L=10,k=4,l=7$.

Comment: Thanks so much. 

Excuse my ignorance but could you extrapolate further how you used the formula to get the solution please?

Comment: I've added in a method which you can use in general for this type of equation.

Comment: Thanks but can it be done without factoring, because as soon as the numbers get large it will be impossible?

Comment: Your equations will always be equivalent to the Diophantine equation $xy=n$ and so will always be equivalent  to factorising the number $n$ e.g. 69 in the above example. (You can use factorising software up to extremely large numbers.)

Comment: Ok thanks! Appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry, 1 last question. If you know half the solution eg 35 34 26 31. Can you work out the other part without factoring?

Comment: In effect you can imagine both series 'starting'  from the common number. The equation therefore takes the same form as before but with $a=b$. We end up  having to factorise an $n$ where we know one way of factorising $n$. This might be of great help for really large numbers. (Of course if the factors you know are $1$ and $n$ you haven't gained anything.)